# How can I make my form field validate asynchronously?

Tags: forms, flutter, async-await

In a form field where I take a username, I want it to be unique. So everytime the user types something I have to check it with my Firebase records. But that happens asynchronously and validator is not working with the async tasks and I have to manually show a snackbar for it. Is there any way I can make this fit into form only?

```
Future<bool> check(String name) async {
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('name', isEqualTo: name.toLowerCase())
    .getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
if (documents.length > 0) return false;
return true;}
```

This is the function I want to call in place of validator of user_name field.

Comment: Use provider or bloc

Comment: yes it does , thanks .